# NetBeans : Trying to create a class file to work with another program

Tags: java

Having trouble compiling these two files to run together.
I get a "can't find or load main class" error or a "erroneous tree" error.
Never asked for help on here before, hope this works :)

```
    package savingsaccount;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SavingsAccount 
    {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double begginingBalance, deposit, withdraw;
    int months;
    double monthlyRate;
    double plus = 0.0;
    double minus = 0.0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the balance at beggining of " +
            "accounting period.");
    begginingBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter number of months in current " +
            "accounting period.");
    months = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the annual interest rate.");
    monthlyRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

    a7main accounting = new a7main();

    for(int month = 1; month<=months; month++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of deposits for month " +
                month + " : ");
        plus = keyboard.nextDouble();
        accounting.deposits(plus);            

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of withdrawals for" +
                " month " + month + ": ");
        minus = keyboard.nextDouble();
        accounting.withdrawals(minus);

        accounting.interest(monthlyRate);
    }

    System.out.println("The account balance is: " + 
            accounting.getBalance());

    System.out.println("The total amount of deposits is:" + plus);

    System.out.println("The total amount of withdrwals is: " + minus);

    System.out.println("The earned interest is: " + 
            accounting.getRate());

    }

    }
```

HERE IS THE CLASS FILE
I am trying to use the methods in this file to calculate and hold the values from the other file.

```
public class a7main
{
private double totalBalance;
private double interestRate;

public a7main(double balance,double rate)
{
    totalBalance = balance;
    interestRate = rate;
}

public void deposits(double deposit)
{
    totalBalance = totalBalance+deposit;
}

public void withdrawals(double withdraw)
{
    totalBalance = totalBalance-withdraw;
}

public void interest(double rate)
{
    interestRate = totalBalance*rate;
}

public double getBalance()
{
    return totalBalance;
}

public double getRate()
{
    return interestRate;
}
}
```

Comment: Is `a7main` also in `package savingsaccount;`

Comment: yes they are both in the same package

Comment: Please so how you are trying to use

Comment: I am trying to use the class file to hold the values from the savingsaccount file.

Comment: The fields in the class file should hold the values of the arguments passed to the methods.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my English was not exact enough for you.  What commands are you typing to compile? What commands are you typing to Execute?

Comment: i am using netbeans and i just hit the play button to compile

Comment: Copy and Paste the error **here**

Comment: run:
Error: Could not find or load main class savingsaccount.SavingsAccount
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Make sure that these classes compile

Comment: does netbeans automatically compile when you try to run a file? The option is greyed out.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I appreciate you.

Comment: No idea, I have never used Netbeans

Comment: Seems your `a7main` has a wrong package declaration. You should also use `package savingsaccount;` in `a7main` too, like what you did in `SavingsAccount`.

Comment: Thank you! your idea worked, but now I have a new error.

Comment: run:
Please enter the balance at beggining of accounting period.
2500
Please enter number of months in current accounting period.
3
Enter the annual interest rate.
2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor a7main in class savingsaccount.a7main cannot be applied to given types;
  required: double,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 at savingsaccount.SavingsAccount.main(SavingsAccount.java:29)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java r

Comment: your issue is here: a7main accounting = new a7main(); As you have an explicit constructor defined in the a7main class, you have to declare explicitly the no args constructor. Anyway IMO by types of questions you are addressing points you in the direction of a good java book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Goad -

> Add package name in a7main class

You have created parameterized constructor and no default constructor.

```
a7main accounting = new a7main();
```

The above line will look for default constructor like

```
public a7main(){
}
```